# Convert java Date to dbf FoxPro datetime format

Tags: java, jodatime, foxpro, dbf

Im trying to create DBF file in FoxPro spec, but idk how to insert date. I dont know how to convert java Date to this:

> FoxPro's field is 2 32bit integers: one stores the date, the other
>   stores the time, stored in reverse byte order. The date integer stores
>   the number of days from 1/1/4712BC. The time integer stores the number
>   of milliseconds from 00:00:00.

Its easy to get days and milliseconds with JodaTime:

```
         DateTime start = new DateTime(-4713, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
         DateTime end = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
         Days days = Days.daysBetween(start, end);
         long millis = end.getMillisOfDay();
```

but how to convert this info to needed format?
For input a date I just use:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
simpledateformat.format(date);
```

and its work fine, but when I try use datetime with `"yyyyMMddHHmmss"`  I see very bad result, like 17.08.33409 12:34:20 (only month is correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VFP has both Date and DateTime field types.

The VFP syntax for inserting a date is:

```
Insert into mytable (mydatefield) values ({^YYYY-MM-DD})
```

or

```
Insert into mytable (mydatefield) values (Date(YYYY,MM,DD))
```

And for a datetime (assuming the field in VFP is a datetime)

```
Insert into mytable (mydatefield) values ({^YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS})
```

or

```
Insert into mytable (mydatefield) values (DateTime(YYYY,MM,DD,HH,MM,SS))
```

So assuming you can extract a text representation of the year, month and day from your Java date you can build up your VFP query from that.

Comment: I make edits in question, still cannot understand where is problem.